# What is this UI element called? A horizontal scrolling menu?

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, navigation, ui-element

I'm talking about a horizontal scrolling menu with "left" and "right" arrows to scroll. I have been seeing this thing everywhere since I started working on a design that uses them. What are they called?

> From the Google Images search results
>   [image: Google images horizonatal scrolling search filter bar]

> From Pinterest search results
>   [image: Pintrest example]

> From Google play store
>   [image: Google play store example]

Comment: hello @Robert thanks for contributing to ux stackexchange, your question is more suitable in stackoverflow since it is regarding technical implementation, here you will find more value in asking questions about ux problems that you are facing, you can check this out for easier onboarding to our community https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
i hope this helps :)

Comment: regarding the naming they are called tabs or navigation tabs, you can find more here https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html#usage

Comment: As said, you need to remove the question about implementation or your question will be closed as being off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As UX Labs mentioned, these are scrolling tabs. Sometimes they are called "scrollable containers." On Windows Phone, they used to be called "Pivot Control."

Sample code: https://codepen.io/srees/pen/pgVLbm

Library: https://material.io/develop/web/components/tabs/scroller/

Medium articles: https://medium.com/flexbox-and-grids/how-to-create-horizontally-scrollable-sections-with-flexbox-60d860f539b2

https://codeburst.io/how-to-create-horizontal-scrolling-containers-d8069651e9c6

Comment: Why would anyone not call these carousel _____ ? In this case, a carousel menu. "Scrollable containers" doesn't define the horizontal or non-vertical aspect of this scrollable container.

I've never seen a carousel go up and down or up, down left and right.

Comment: @insidesin Because they don't go round like a carousel. With this UI, you can only scroll left and right from end to end, whereas a carousel does not have an end.

Comment: @Levano there is such a thing as a carousel that doesn't repeat or reset. You don't wonder why a modal can be full-screen, why worry about a carousel that doesn't reverse/repeat? It's a name that fits, more so than a "scrollable container". Unless we're literally talking about a div with a scroll overflow, which isn't the case for most of these except maybe the Google Play store.